# Replacing a field in text file with the result of a system command

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Using Bash commands, I would like to substitute field 3 of each line of a text file with the result of a command which takes the original field 3 as an argument. Fields are `/`-delimited.

Input file:

```
./REMOTE_PARENT_DIR/0x134000564f:0x4c:0x0/test_runs/testgsi_O1
./REMOTE_PARENT_DIR/0x134000564f:0x4c:0x0/test_runs/testgsi_O2
...
```

Desired output file (don't print field 1 and 2, field 3 will be result of Unix  command, print remaining fields):

```
/scratch/000011/rin/test_runs/testgsi_O1
/scratch/000011/rin/test_runs/testgsi_O2
...
```

Command to translate field 3 into normal path components:

```
hostx#lfs fid2path /scratch [0x134000564f:0x4c:0x0]
/scratch/000011/rin
```

Maybe use `awk` to grab the relevant field then `sed` with command substitution then spit out the new line?

This prints out the bit I need but not sure how to substitute into the lines of the file:

```
awk -F "/" '{ system("/bin/lfs fid2path /scratch " $3) }' outfile.70.sample.tmp
```

Comment: Figured it out with simple loop, will post once I figure out how to get it formatted decently.

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` one-liner would help to achieve your goals:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"; OFS="/" } { cmd = "/bin/lfs fid2path /scratch "$3; cmd | getline path; close(cmd); for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) { path = path""OFS""$i};print path }' your_input_file.txt
```

- Here we assign the field separator `FS` and output field separator `OFS` built-in variables to a slash `/` in the `BEGIN` rule before any output is read and processed.
- Then we create a command `cmd` variable based on your desired shell call with the third field `$3` as argument.
- We execute `cmd` shell command and pipe its output into the built-in command `getline` and put it in the variable `path`.
- The close() function is called to close `cmd` after it produced its output and to ensure the command runs for each record.
- Then using a `for` loop we concatenate the values starting with the 4th field until the end of the line to `path` variable separated with `OFS`.
- ***Finally*** we print out the desired, changed path. Since I don't have the `/bin/lfs` command installed i just tested it with `cmd = "echo "$3" | cut -d':' -f2"` to see the results and it looks fine.

***For example `paths.txt`:***

```
./REMOTE_PARENT_DIR/0x134000564f:0x4c:0x0/test_runs/testgsi_O1
./REMOTE_PARENT_DIR/0x134000564f:0x4c:0x0/test_runs/testgsi_O2
```

***Example call:***

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"; OFS="/" } { cmd = "echo "$3" | cut -d':' -f2"; cmd | getline path; close(cmd); for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) { path = path""OFS""$i};print path }' paths.txt
```

***Produces the result:***

```
0x4c/test_runs/testgsi_O1
0x4c/test_runs/testgsi_O2
```

Where a specific part is extracted from the third awk field `$3` using a shell command `cut -d':' -f2`. That is the `2nd` field from the colon (`:`) separated string: `0x134000564f:0x4c:0x0`.

Answer (score 0):

> I hope understand your problem correct, otherwise tell me to delete this
>   answer please.

If you do not mind using **Perl** then you can do that very easy and straightforward

Consider the following **one-liner**

```
perl -F'/' -ne '$F[2]="add-some-text/"; print @F[2..$#F]' file
```

It reads the file line by line, and substitutes the filed 2 with `add-some-text`  which has this output:

```
all-some-text/test_runstestgsi_O1
all-some-text/test_runstestgsi_O2
```

Now if you want to use a command, just instead of a simple text use a command but with back-stick operator in Perl:

```
perl -F'/' -ne '$F[2]=`date "+%H:M:S"`; print @F[2..$#F]' file
```

or `qx()` which is more readable:

```
perl -F'/' -ne '$F[2]=qx(date "+%H:M:S"); print @F[2..$#F]' file
```

Also if you want to **pass an argument** you can do it as well:

```
perl -F'/' -ne '$F[2]=qx(echo -n $F[2]/); print @F[2..$#F]' file
```

and eventually for substitution just use `-i.bak` before `-F`. It will create a back-up file like `file.bak` and modify your original one.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTFILE03=tmpfile

while IFS=/ read first second fid remainder
do
    REAL=`/bin/lfs fid2path /scratch $fid`
    echo "$REAL/$remainder"
done <"input.70"  >$OUTFILE03
```

Comment: Hi.  Can you give a brief explanation as to how this solves the original question?